# builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Что означает эта ошибка: builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable?

Вот код для контекста:
Данная програм должна складывать числа с оснаваниями от 0 до 50 включитльно без перевода в 10-ую систему исчисления.

```
def plus(Num1, Num2, base):
    p = 0
    Num_Tab = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+-/8=~!@#№$%^&?'
    New_Num = ''
    Min = min(len(Num1),len(Num2))
    Max = max(len(Num1),len(Num2))
    i = 0
    if len(Num1) > len(Num2):
        Max = Num1
        Min = Num2
    elif len(Num1) < len(Num2):
        Max = Num2
        Min = Num1
    else:
        Max = 0
    if Max - Min > 0:
        B = Max - Min
    else: 
        B = 0

    def sum(Num1, Num2):
        a = Num1 + Num2 + p
        if a > base:
            p = 1
            return Num_Tab[a - base]
        else:
            p = 0
            return Num_Tab[a]

    while Min:
        Min-=1
        New_Num = sum(Num_Tab.find[Num1[i]], Num_Tab.find[Num2[i]]) + New_Num
        i+=1
    while B:
        if p:
            New_Num = Num_Tab[Num_Tab.find[Num1[i]] + p] + New_Num 
            p = 0
        else:
            New_Num = Num_Tab[Num_Tab.find[Num1[i]]] + New_Num  
    return New_Num
```

Comment: Добавляйте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы не правильно используете метод `find`

место `find[]` надо писать `find()`

Comment: Просто глаз-алмаз :)